# Tracert access is denied in windows 7, side-by-side configuration incorrect

Tags: windows, windows-7, networking, permissions, traceroute

I use windows 7. This is my personal computer. When I tried to use tracert today in command prompt with administrative privileges, it says access denied. I have used to command in the past without any problems. I tried to change the owner going to the location of tracert.exe in system32 folder, but cannot change the permissions either. Only trustedInstaller has full control. Why is there suddenly an access denied? How do I fix it?

When I just run the command tracert, cmd returns the following error -

The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.

Comment: Are you piping the output to a file, using `> drive:\path\filename`?

Comment: No, just running the command on command prompt

Answer (score 0):

**I am going to assume that you're piping the output to a file, so will provide an answer based on that.**

If you're writing a `CMD` output to file, you must ensure that the process has the required access to the destination folder. In a corporate environment, writing out `tracert 8.8.4.4 > c:\trace.log` is likely to be blocked by group policy, as will other directories. I would suggest creating a new folder as `c:\temp`, or if that already exists then change your commend to output to that directory.

Access denied messages from the command line more often than not refer to a permissions issue writing/reading files to/from the disk rather than a privelage escalation issue executing the command.

Comment: I have used the command before without any complications, suddenly there is a permissions issue. How did this happen on it's own?